# Set MySql read-only from K8s cluster

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, readonly, consistency

I have a Kubernetes cluster running with MySql app (5.7.32 MySql version).
I'm trying to make MySql app be in a consistency mode, using this command:

> "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; SET_GLOBAL read_only = ON;"

When I run this command from **inside the app** - **it works** (getting error when trying to write when the DB is locked):

> kubectl exec -ti mysql-0 -c mysql -- mysql
>
> > mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; SET_GLOBAL read_only = ON; INSERT INTO mydb.mytable VALUES('hello');

But When I run this command using **kubectl exec** command - **it doesn't work** (this command doesn't fail, and it is able to write to the DB):

> kubectl exec -ti mysql-0 -c mysql -- mysql -h mysql -e "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; SET_GLOBAL read_only = ON; INSERT INTO mydb.mytable VALUES('hello'); "

I also created a **grant privileged user**, it didn't help:

> kubectl exec -ti mysql-0 -c mysql -- mysql -h mysql -e "CREATE USER $USER@'$HOST' IDENTIFIED BY '$PASS'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO $USER@'$HOST';"

> kubectl exec -ti mysql-0 -c mysql -- mysql -h mysql -u $USER -p$PASS -e "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; SET_GLOBAL read_only = ON; INSERT INTO mydb.mytable VALUES('hello'); "

How Can I bring my MySql app to be in a read-only state without running the command from inside the application?

Thanks!

Comment: hello welcome on this website this question might be better suited on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland, I posted there as well https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/290046/set-mysql-read-only-from-k8s-cluster, although I'm not sure if it is a MySql issue or Kubernetes issue